# How to format text including " ` " character

Tags: support, formatting

The text I want to format is:

> ...  that Alt Gr + `  gives | ...

into

> ... that <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> gives `|` ...

What I did was using `<kbd>` and enclose " | " with  " ` " but when code formatting character is involved, it gets messy as above. How do I escape the format?

Comment: Edited. Does that help?

Comment: oh, god.. and I'm supposed to be a soon-to-be-C/C++ programmer...

Comment: Much more backtick formatting in [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189)

Answer (score 6):

Just use the escape character: \